# netstatコマンドで表示されるUDPの待ち受けポートが、同じポート番号でPID違いのものがある

Tags: windows, network

Windows 11 Pro

コマンドプロンプトで `netstat -ano` を実行すると、UDPでは同じポート番号でPIDが異なる行があります。

例えば、以下の画面コピーでは、UDPの5353ポートにはPIDが8104や12316などの行があります。（PID:8104はMicrosoft Edgeで、12316はGoogle Chromeでした）

ポート番号の役割は、どのアプリケーションにデータを渡すのかの識別に使われると理解しています。

UDPの5353ポートでMicrosoft EdgeとGoogle Chromeが待ち受けをしていると見えるので、UDPの5353ポートに届いたデータをMicrosoft Edgeに渡すのかGoogle Chromeに渡すのかが判断できないと思うのですが、なぜ、これで問題ないのでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: この辺の記事が参考になりそうです。['ss' shows multiple listening pids for same port](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/593057), [UDP connection appearing multiple times in netstat command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49388664/9014308), [Can two applications listen to the same port?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694144/9014308)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

まず5353/udpは[マルチキャストDNS(mDNS)](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%9E%E3%83%AB%E3%83%81%E3%82%AD%E3%83%A3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88DNS)です。名前の通り[IPマルチキャスト](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP%E3%83%9E%E3%83%AB%E3%83%81%E3%82%AD%E3%83%A3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88)通信を行います。

UDPは一方通行のプロトコルです。この点を利用してIPマルチキャストでは同一の内容を複数の受信者に送信できます。（これに対し広く使われているTCPでは双方向通信を行うため、複数の受信者がそれぞれ応答を行うと通信として矛盾が発生します。）

複数の受信者とは、異なるコンピューターでも構いませんし、コンピューター内の複数のプログラムでも構わないわけです。今回観測されたのは後者です。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
上記の場合、UDPの5353ポートに届いたデータは、Microsoft EdgeとGoogle Chromeの両方に渡されるということで理解いたしました。